# Relational Model Setup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

Please forgive me if this has been answered already, I just can't really find an explanation/example for what I need to do.

I have two models, a `Dealer` model and a `Location` model. When a `Location` is created, it has to be created for a `Dealer`. A `Dealer` has a `ShipToLocation` and a `BillToLocation` associated with it but there can also be `Locations` created for a `Dealer` that the `Dealer` isn't currently related to. I need to setup the models in such a way that I can have dropdown lists of `Locations` that have been created for the `Dealer` that the user can select to be added as the "current" ShipTo or BillTo location. I hope I explained that correctly...

Here are my model setups but I'm getting a foreign key constraint error:

```
public class Dealer : BaseEntity
{
   [Key]
   public int DealerId { get; set; }

   public string DealerName { get; set; }
   public virtual Location ShipToLocation { get; set; }
   public virtual Location BillToLocation { get; set; }
}


public class Location : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string LocationStateProvince { get; set; }
    public string LocationCountry { get; set; }

    //public int DealerId { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("DealerId")]
    public virtual Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
}
```

And the current error I get when I run the database migration is:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Dealers_dbo.Locations_ShipToLocation_LocationId". The conflict occurred in database "CoinWeb", table "dbo.Locations", column 'LocationId'.
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following statement is true for your case

a customer have many location and location can be shared by many customer . so i think the relation ship is M---M so create a new model  called CustomerLocations

```
public class CustomerLocations: BaseEntity
    {
       [Key]
       public int ID { get; set; }

      public Customer Customer {get;set;}
       public virtual LocationType LocationType { get; set; }
       public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    }

public enum LocationType{

Billing=1,
Shipping=2
}
```

Comment: Sort of. A location can only be added to one `Dealer`, so it's one to one there. Many `Locations` can be created for a `Dealer` though. This is where the list comes in. For a `Dealer`, there could  be hundreds of possible `ShipTo Locations` in the list. The user selects one that becomes their  "current" `ShipToLocation`, stored as the `ShipToLocationId`. That same situation, including the same list, is used for `BillToLocation`. A `Location` cannot be for any `Dealer` and the list should only display `Locations` created for that Dealer.